# The difference between render(...) and g.render(...) in grails

Tags: grails

```
I have the following bit in a controller:

            def myJSON = [

                    'form' : g.render(template: '/information/form', model:informationInstance)
            ]

            render myJSON as JSON
```

... and wonder what's the difference between and purpose of **render()** and **g.render()**??
And where does '**g**' come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The g is the namespace for the Grails tag library.  It is automatically injected into controllers and views.  In a controller, you access it as g.XXX() rather than `<g:XXX />`.  There really is no difference in how they function under the covers except with how the controller triggers its response.